# Which class would be considered the strongest given high ability scores?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, class

Hey first time asking here, but I'm making a character for a game and rolled the insane stats of 18 17 14 14 14 13 highset to lowest and I wonder which class would be considered getting the most out of these stats, I'm considering a MAD class but I'm not too strong with the mechanics and such and would like to hear what you guys think.

The campaign will be set in a rather advanced world, guns will be mass produced in the world and count as martial weapons. It will be an undead infested world as well, though I have no idea if the DM is trying to mislead us and we'll be fighting fey instead, he does that occassionally. We are allowed access to all paizo books except for the latest class guide book since he doesn't have that, prepared arcane spellcasters are banned as PCs.

As stated I'm not too good with the core mechanics of Pathfinder but I really want to get the most out of these stats. I always try to build first a strong "character sheet" and then build an interesting character around that, and to distill my question further I'm wondering what type of combat playstyle would benefit the most out of these stats, so far I've come up with:

- Sword and Board twf
- Normal twf
- Bow build
- Gun build

The other classes in the campaign are ranger (I'm guessing bow), rogue twf, unknown and unknown. I've heard that we have no casters at all.

The campaign is planned to run for a long time and we are starting at level 1 with a free item with a magical enhancement that can cost up to 2000gp.

I'm not sure what else to fill out, thanks for the pointers as well for formulating my question!

Comment: What resources are available? At what level is the campaign starting? What's the campaign setting? Are there any house rules that could affect advice (e.g. psionics are banned, no third party material)?

Comment: O, hey, welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Visit the help center. Push the `Help` buttons. Those things are useful. I'll let you know, though, that while folks are happy to help, they need *a lot* of information to do so. The more you can tell us about your upcoming game and the other characters and ideas for your own, the better.

Comment: What do you mean with "playstyle"? Character tactics? Because the thing I'm used to call playstyle focuses more on if having a strong character is important or not to the game.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but yeah, you really need to state what is your goal, what is your definition of powerful, what resources are allowed, etc.